# ColdFusion, BigDecimal cannot be used as an array

Tags: arrays, struct, coldfusion, cfml

I am trying to perform a few simple tasks with an array of structures that I have and feel like I'm almost done with my solution but am having some last minute trouble. I am trying to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Create a struct with the following values; id, name, int arr[].
2. I am using a FOR loop to iterate over an array of values like ID, name, sub id.
3. For each item in my list, I am trying to make the decision if I've seen the struct before and if its in my agencies Array.
4. If its not there, add the current struct to an array. If its already present in the array then add the current sub id to the int arr[] entry of the struct.

When I run my code below I keep getting the error, "BigDecimal cannot be used as an array" and I don't understand what's happening. I am new to CFSCRIPT so perhaps I'm either not getting the arr[] values out of the struct or not defining my struct correct so the third value is of Array type.

```
remote array function getCurrAgenciesList(String Acct_Id) returnformat="JSON"
    {

        include "qry_getCurrentAssignedRepoAgenciesAll.cfm";

        //define arr to hold values...
        var agenciesArr = [];
        var recordLength = getCurrentAssignedRepoAgencies.RecordCount;

            for(agency in getCurrentAssignedRepoAgencies)
            {
                currentStruct = {id=agency.repoID, name=agency.repoName, relatedColl=agency.collatSub};
                var structArrIndex = arrayOfStructsFind(agenciesArr, "id", agency.repoID);

                if(structArrIndex eq 0)
                {
                    //add new struct to agenciesArr
                    ArrayAppend(agenciesArr,currentStruct,"true");
                }
                else
                {
                    //find current struct in array using index from before...
                    var collFromStr = agenciesArr[structArrIndex]['relatedColl'];
                    //add current collatsub to array, append.
                    var updatedStruct = ArrayAppend(collFromStr,agency.collatSub);
                    //reassign updated arr[] struct value back in array.
                    agenciesArr[structArrIndex]['relatedColl'] = collFromStr;
                }

            }
                //return...
                return agenciesArr;
        }

        function arrayOfStructsFind(Array, SearchKey, Value)
        {
                var result = 0;
                var i = 1;
                var key = "";
                for (i=1;i lte arrayLen(array);i=i+1)
                {
                   for (key in array[i])
                   {
                     if(array[i][key]==Value and key == SearchKey)
                     {
                        result = i;
                        return result;
                     }
                   }
                }

            return result;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I feel I'm stuck on this one last thing or there's something I am missing. Any feedback is welcome.

UPDATE the error happens at line 27,

```
var updatedStruct = ArrayAppend(collFromStr,agency.collatsub);
```

UPDATE 3:39PM

I believe the issue is not related to the above line but this line:

```
var collFromStr = agenciesArr[structArrOmdex]['relatedColl'];
```

I am asking for an array to be returned from the struct from key, relatedColl. I am thinking only an integer is return so when the next Array Append operation is performed the code explodes. So, how does one create an array inside a struct in Cold Fusion\CFSCRIPT????

Comment: at which line does the error occur?

Comment: I updated the original description to where the exact error is happening.

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayappend.html). (Edit) ArrayAppend returns a boolean, not a structure.  Not sure exactly what the code is doing but ... be sure to scope *all* function local variables (including loop indeces and query objects). Also, may not be an issue but ... be aware structures are passed by reference.

Comment: I believe the problem is most likely this:

Comment: *RE: I am thinking only an integer is return* You can use cfdump at strategic points to verify what is actually happening in the code and if indeed that is the issue. Providing a runnable sample of the query data (with dummy values) would make it a lot easier for folks to assist. [QueryNew()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querynew.html) is great for that purpose.

Comment: FYI, rolled back last edit since solution was moved to an official "answer".

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by making the following changes:

- Re-defined the struct definition to have an array type as the third element.
- After doing this it looks like the search needed to be modified so I switched the ordering of my key, value if statement.

I also gathered a great amount of information from [this link](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/implicit-structures-in-coldfusion-8). It is wonderful.

**Final Code:**

```
remote array function getCurrAgenciesList(String Acct_Id) returnformat="JSON"
{

include "qry_getCurrentAssignedRepoAgenciesAll.cfm";

//define arr to hold values...
var agenciesArr = [];
var recordLength = getCurrentAssignedRepoAgencies.RecordCount;

    for(agency in getCurrentAssignedRepoAgencies)
    {
        arr = [agency.collatSub];
        currentStruct = {id=agency.repoID, name=agency.repoName, relatedColl=arr};
        var structArrIndex = arrayOfStructsFind(agenciesArr, "id", agency.repoID);

        if(structArrIndex eq 0)
        {
            //add new struct to agenciesArr
            ArrayAppend(agenciesArr,currentStruct,"true");
        }
        else
        {
            //find current struct in array using index from before...
            var collFromStr = agenciesArr[structArrIndex]['relatedColl'];
            //add current collatsub to array, append.
            ArrayAppend(collFromStr,agency.collatSub,"true");
            //reassign updated arr[] struct value back in array.
            agenciesArr[structArrIndex]['relatedColl'] = collFromStr;
        }

    }
        //return...
        return agenciesArr;
}

function arrayOfStructsFind(Array, SearchKey, Value)
{
        var result = 0;
        var i = 1;
        var key = "";
        for (i=1;i lte arrayLen(array);i=i+1)
        {
           for (key in array[i])
           {
             if(key == SearchKey and array[i][key]==Value)
             {
                result = i;
                return result;
             }
           }
        }

    return result;


 }
```